# Deploy jar from another EAR

Tags: jboss, ejb, wildfly, cdi

I have 4 applications that rely on the same `jar` (where some `EJB`s are located), but, because of the explicit dependency in `pom.xml`, I’m having problems with the build that not always consider the right version, that’s why I had the idea of doing the deploy of my jar as an ear and reference it as a dynamic module in the other ear.

The problem is  that the dynamic module is not deployed, what gives me: `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies`.

I’ve tried as many `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` configurations as possible, but I didn’t have success with any of them.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>   
        <dependencies>
          <module name="deployment.a.ear" export="true"/>
          <module name="deployment.a.ear.a.jar" export="true" /> 
        </dependencies> 
    </deployment> 
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: What do your poms look like?

Comment: Before, I has explicit dependency on this ear, but now, I need sync this EJB over other apps whithout rebuild.

      <dependency>
            <groupId>deployment.a</groupId>
            <artifactId>deployment.a</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>org.hibernate</artifactId>
                    <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>${deployment.a.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: You probably just need to mark the dependency as `<scope>provided</scope>` if you've already deployed the JAR to the server.

Comment: Still dont work, my problem occur only in deploy time. 

The app dont deploy EJB S from jar in other deployment, if I declare the dependency inside the app work fine.

Maybe this issue is ClassLoader or Deployment stages related.

Comment: Am I correct that you deploy your ejb.jar to WildFly, then you deploy a WAR that depends on the ejb.jar?

Comment: Yes, but the ejb.jar is inside a EAR

Comment: If the ejb.jar is inside the EAR you need to remove or set the `<ear-subdeployments-isolated/>` to `false`.

Comment: Now, I try this approach, but I got the same error, the EJB dont deploy over module in another EAR: `Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IEjb] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.xyz.Ejb]"}}`

Comment: That looks like `com.xyz.Ejb` is defined in two spots. Is the ejb.jar by chance in the EAR and the WAR?

Comment: No, `com.xyz.Ejb` is defined in EJB EAR only and I try load in WAR EAR by the jboss-deployment-structure, but only class reference exist in WAR EAR. EJB S from dynamic module are never deploied.